# Probability of obtaining $p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, analytic-number-theory

Given, a prime $q$ what is the probability of obtaining a prime $p$ such that $ a^{(p-1)/q} \equiv 1 \mod p$. Here, $a$ is any given integer and by $ a^{(p-1)/q} \equiv 1 \mod p$ we mean that the remainder on dividing $a^{(p-1)/q}$ by $p$ is $1$

In a paper I found out that the probability is $\frac{1}{q}$. But, I do not know how this was obtained. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is $a$?  Obtaining how?  And what does $a^{p-1/q}$ even mean mod $p$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $a$ is any given integer. By $a^{p-1/q} \equiv 1 \mod p$ we mean that the remainder on dividing $a^{p-1/q}$ by $p$ is $1$.

Comment: Does this imply finding a $p$ such that $a^{p-1/q}$ is an integer?

Comment: What variable here has a random distribution, and what distribution is that?

Comment: @aschepler It does imply finding an integer $p$ such that $a^{p-1/q}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. Regarding the distribution, I am not sure what distribution it would be. The fact is that this is a problem found in an Analytic Number Theory paper where the author stated that the probability of finding a $p$ is $\frac{1}{q}$ .

Comment: Then there's not enough information to answer, unless someone recognizes/guesses the result you saw. Without a probability distribution, there can be no interesting probabilities.

Comment: @aschepler http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~agboola/teaching/2005/winter/old-115A/murty.pdf Kindly check this pdf's 3rd page.

Comment: I see. Notice that page 3 describe an intuitive argument, and NOT a proof. It relates to a variant of Dirichlet's theorem, which gives an asymptotic frequency. It can sometimes be useful to think of those as similar to probabilities, although they aren't really.

Comment: I take it $a^{p-1/q}$ is supposed to be $a^{(p-1)/q}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes.

Comment: Given a prime $q$, and given a prime $p$ such that $q$ divides $p-1$, and given $a$ relatively prime to $p$, the number $a^{(p-1)/q}$ will have the property that when you raise it to the power $q$ you get $1\bmod p$. There are $q$ numbers mod $p$ with the property that when you raise to the power $q$ you get $1\bmod p$. Heuristically, these $q$ numbers are all equally likely, so the probability that $a^{(p-1)/q}\equiv1\bmod p$ is $1/q$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not understand how you we can say that there are $q$ numbers $\mod p$ with the property that  when you raise to the power $q$ we get $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: The multiplicative group of the integers modulo $p$ are a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Let $g$ be a generator of this group, and let $h=g^{(p-1)/q}$. Then the $q$ residues $1,h,h^2,\dots,h^{q-1}$ are the residues which, when raised to the power $q$, give $1\bmod p$.

Comment: Are we OK now, cab?

Comment: Earth to cab – come in, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes we are ok. Thanks

Comment: Good. Why not write up what you now understand about the question, and post it as an answer?